# Align the exported result from code analyzer in excel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, visual-studio-2013

I have done Ctrl+A and ctrl+c to export code analyzer result in excel.

But the results are not aligned. I want to align the result so that the result will be feasible for others to read. I have around 9000 Reported issues from code analyzer. So i cant manually align the result.

I am using visual studio 2013

Please some one help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the code analyzer results into a notepad++ file and save. Then, import this file into excel as a tab delimited file.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I just need one more favor .. Can you please tel me hoe to import error category(Like design,coding) from code analyzer report.. When i Do ctrl+A and Ctrl+c its not coming